# Can't get access to http://localhost:80 on running apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, localhost, server

On running apache server in ubuntu 14.04 I get `"This webpage is not available"` in browser or `"curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"` using `$ curl localhost`. Besides I can connect to 127. * . * . *  (e.g. 127.0.0.2) - doesn't work only 127.0.0.1

**/etc/hosts**

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
 127.0.1.1  al-ubuntu
 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
 ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

When I change port e.g. `Listen 82` then I can connect to localhost:82 or 127.0.0.1:82

**There are no any processes using port 80, except apache2:**

`$sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

=> `tcp6       0     0 :::80      :::*         LISTEN      7127/apache2`

**There are three files in /var/log/apache2/:**

```
access.log, error.log and other_vhosts_access.log
```

When **restarting apache2:** `$ tail -f error.log`

```
 [Thu Feb 19 16:03:19.570066 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1285] AH00169: 
 caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 [Thu Feb 19 16:03:20.673519 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3454] AH00163:   
 Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 configured -- resuming normal  
 operations
 [Thu Feb 19 16:03:20.674355 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3454] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

When **connecting to localhost** in all log files - nothing.

I installed apache on other ubuntu14.04 system and all works.

What cause blocking port 80, do you know in what the problem is?

Comment: Can you tail the Apache error log when you restart it and when you try connecting and it doesn't work?  tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: ratsbane, I added this information to the question.

Comment: did you have firewall on server ? you should check selinux and os firewall (iptables) status

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my apache's httpd.conf file, I had

```
Listen 198.166.2.1:8000
```

then I changed it to:

```
Listen 8000
```

and it worked both with localhost and with the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

This question related to https://serverfault.com/questions/670575/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-1-port-80.

No any process blocking port 80. Problem related to firewall NAT rules which are redirecting connections to 80 port to another disabled port. It fixed with removing these rules.

Comment: Not really. In my case the firewall is not even enabled

Comment: Edited: for those who are using "iptables", make sure to run `iptables -L` to see if there is any rule available. Services like `iptables`, `firewalld`, `ufw` while not running - their rules may still enforce.