# Apache/xampp not working on ubuntu port 80

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, xampp

Xampp/apache have been working fine until today. Basically, if I configure xampp to start apache on any other port, it seems to work fine, but not on port 80. If I navigate to localhost (or 127.0.0.1) it says site can't be reached/connection refused.

I verified netstat while xampp has started apache:

> sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80\|:443'

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7351/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      7351/httpd
```

If I shut down apache with xampp the netstat shows 0 results. I also tried running apache with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`. That doesn't work either and in that case netstat shows

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      8271/apache2
```

I have no idea what has happened, it has been working fine until today. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling xampp again (with the provided uninstaller). Only thing I remember having changed to my system since last time is installing ruby and prax. (I also ran prax stop already). Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597411/cant-get-access-to-http-localhost80-on-running-apache-server

Comment: And this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/670575/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-1-port-80 . Maybe you have some NAT rule like explained in the question of this link.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is some NAT rules. You have to disable them as stated here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/670575/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-1-port-80

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port 80 and the SSL port 443 or if you  want try [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) is a server php with graphic interface how is like wamp on windows

Answer (score 0):

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

**Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80 in Ubuntu========**

That's a type of problem that has been solved via the below code.

Just open your terminal

►Commands

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

after that just add this line at the end and save.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then return and restart

►Commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```